# How do I assign objects and get foreign keys etc

Tags: apex, compile-error

Here's a basic function I have.  I don't regularly use Apex, so I'm not sure how to address the various parents and children of objects and assign them, I'm sure there's a tricky bit with the Ids.

```
public void basicfxn(Map<Id, Child__c> newRecords){
        List<Child__c> children = [select Id, Parent__c, Days_After_Create__c, Next_Child__c from Child__c where Parent__c in :newRecords.Parent__c order by Parent__c.Id, Days_After_Create__c desc]; //Inexplicably here Parent__c does not exist.  Its' a master detail relationship
        
        Boolean start = True;
        Child__c child = new Child__c();  //Invalid type
        Parent__c parent = new Parent__c();

        for (Child__c c:children){
             if (start){
                child = haskins.Id; //Illegal assignment from Id to Child__c
                parent = haskins.Deequence__c.Id; //A non foreign key field can not be reference in a path expressions
                start = False;
             } else {
                 if (haskins.Parent__c.Id == parent.Id){
                    haskins.Next_Child__c = child.Id;
                    child = haskins.Id;
                 } else {
                     priordp = haskins.Deequence__c.Id;
                     haskins.Next_Deequence_Line__c = null;  //Can we even do this with the nulls?
                     priordp2 = haskins.Id;
                 }
             }
        }
        update children;
```

How does the syntax actually work to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
... where Parent__c in :newRecords.Parent__c ...
```

Lists of sObjects can't automatically aggregate the values together, you need to pull them out first:

```
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Child__c child: newRecords.values()) {
  parentIds.add(child.Parent__c);
}
```

---

The `__c` notation is when you want the value of a field, and the `__r` notation is used to traverse relationships.

```
... order by Parent__c.Id ...
```

Should be:

```
... order by Parent__c ...
```

Do not traverse the relationship to get the lookup Id. It's inefficient and unnecessary.

---

```
    Child__c child = new Child__c();  //Invalid type
```

No reason why this should be, perhaps just a typo in the original code.

---

`haskins` is never defined, perhaps you meant `c`?

---

In general, you can't assign objects between types, so:

```
child = haskins.Id;
```

Is trying to assign an Id to a Child__c, which  won't work. Perhaps you meant:

```
child = haskins;
```

---

```
parent = haskins.Deequence__c.Id; //A non foreign key field can not be reference in a path expressions
```

Again, `__c` are field values, `__r` is a relationship. You could write:

```
parent  = haskins.Deequence__c;
```

Or:

```
parent  = haskins.Deequence__r.Id;
```

Again, avoid using `__r.Id`.

---

```
haskins.Next_Deequence_Line__c = null;  //Can we even do this with the nulls?
```

Yes, null is a legal type virtually all types of fields, except for Checkbox fields, which must be set to true or false if provided.

---

`priordp` and `priordp2` are both not defined here. Just in case, if they're specified outside of the method, you're probably doing something wrong, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Meta comment. I wonder how you find energy to be so answering so many questions or to answer in a detailed manner. However you find that, we appreciate your effort.

Comment: @metasync I love helping people, it's actually one of my driving principles. I started programming as a child, and my love for technology comes from that. I also regularly volunteered and helped out where I could. I'm not very strong or agile, but I do have a sharp mind, so it makes sense to me to use what gifts I have to help the world as much as I can. Thanks for the comment, and rest assured I plan on doing this for as long as I can.

Comment: This is fantastic!  So is your site, which I review regularly